# Fieldset attribute not working when using it over a list in struts2 application

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

Hi look at my code in jsp.

```
    <s:iterator value="answeredquestions" status="status" var="question">
  <fieldset>
    <legend><s:property value="Question"/></legend>
    <s:property value="QuestionNumber"/>    
    <table><s:radio label="Answer" name="answeredquestions[%{#status.index}].UserAnswer" list="AnswersOptions" /></table>
   </fieldset>
   </s:iterator>
      <
```

The List seems to work fine 
But the in the First List Item the radio buttons wont come inside the fieldset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation about themes http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/themes-and-templates.html. By default Struts2 uses `xhtml` theme. In this theme elements are being put in table cells. You can change it by specifying `theme="simple"` attribute in tags. NOTE: if you use `simple` theme you will loose field errors.